# How to quickly start two applications in windows?

Tags: windows, batch, cmd.exe

I start application A and application B, that modifies my application A. B opens a cmd window where I get asked for options. I alaways chose the same options in B. So what I want to know if it is possible to start both applications and enter the right inputs in B with a single click? Maybe a batch file could do that?

I wouldn't want to use a tool like Autohotkeys for that, that just allows mouse and keyboard macros.

Comment: If B does not provide any command line parameters or other means of entering the options programmatically, I guess Autohotkey is probably your best choice. I don't understand why you have concerns to use this.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question correctly, it probably depends on whether app B can accept those options directly from the shell used to launch it instead of interactively via the shell that it spawns when you start it. If it does, you should be able to write a batch script similar to this to start them both up automatically.

`/a` and `/b` are command line parameters that would correspond to the options you’re setting in the shell that app B spawns when you run it.

```
START C:\Path\To\AppA.EXE
START C:\Path\To\AppB.EXE /a valueA /b valueB
```

And if you wanted to get even fancier, you could parameterize the option values `valueA` and `valueB` so that you can set those on the fly when you run your batch script to make it more flexible. That way you don’t need to make code changes if you decide you need to enter them differently for some reason. I think that would look something like this in your script:

```
START C:\Path\To\AppA.EXE
START C:\Path\To\AppB.EXE /a %1 /b %2
```

And then you would run your batch file like this to inject values into those options:

```
C:\Path\To\script.bat valueA valueB
```

Either way you do it, you could then just double-click the batch file (or a shortcut to it) to have it run and open up both apps.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a batch file (.bat) like:

```
START C:\Windows\ApplicationA.exe
START C:\Windows\ApplicationB.exe
```

That you click and launches both of them

You could use this method to run however many files you want

Comment: How to include the options in B? B opens a cmd window where I can either type 1, 2 or 3 and it will chose that option and close right after.

Comment: So you want applicationB, to ask you 1, 2, or 3 and then launch applicationA differently, depending on the answer?

Comment: No application B just does that. It opens cmd and waits for user input.

Comment: Do then, you just need to start the 2 files, which is what I showed here